# Issues unlocking sheets in workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have protected worksheets in a workbook and when I right-click on the sheet name and unprotect the sheet, columns I have specifically protected in that sheet, go back to being protected after I do one action on the sheet. That one "thing" could be, clicking into a cell that has a formula, which was previously protected, making a slight adjustment to the formula, clicking enter, then the sheet will go back to being protected and I have unprotect it again. It can even be, after unprotecting the sheet, I move from cell C4 and click on cell F8, the sheet will go back to being protected. I know the password, I enter it successfully every time and I've locked other columns in specific worksheets with the same password.

Is there a way to permanently unprotect these sheets? Or am I doing something wrong when I try to unprotect them?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the workbook Macro-Enabled (i.e. has VBA code)?

Comment: @Twisty Yes, it has VBA code in almost every sheet.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the VBA that is re-protecting your sheets?

Comment: @JSmart523 It seems like it was. I has a line: `Worksheets("JE").Protect Password:="ImportLCPA17", UserInterfaceOnly:=True` that I think was re-protecting the sheet. Can only confirm that for me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact your workbook is macro-enabled, it's likely there is VBA code that is automatically re-protecting the worksheets.

The VBA method `.Protect` ([Documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-protect-method-excel?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) will be present in whatever code would be responsible for this.  Search the VBA Project for this string and modify it according to your needs.